# Optimising Mongo Aggregation Query by Conditional Lookups

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

so I have a collection **events** that looks like this:

**events**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c8f4d3bbbf999bd7d1cc11c"),
    "category" : "Comment",
    "reference_field" : ObjectId("5c8f4ba4bbf999bbb056984f"), // Object id of a document in the COMMENT collection
    "deleted_reference_field" : "Not Deleted",
    "summary" : "Some string"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c8b7e6dbbf99995bdcb37ac"),
    "category" : "Comment",
    "reference_field" : ObjectId("5c8b3fe9bbf9997e1f18c816"), // object id of a document in the PROJECT collection
    "deleted_reference_field" : "Project",
    "summary" : "Here is a new comment!"
}
```

So as you can see, both the documents of the `event` collection reference different collections. This is determined by the `deleted_reference_field` attribute.

- If its value is *Not Deleted* then the `reference_field` contains the objectId it reference the `Comment` collection.
- If the value is `Project` or any such string, then the `reference_field` contains the object id of the collection it should refer to. In this example, it refers to the `Project` collection.

I need to perform a `$lookup` to populate the corresponding `reference_field`. In order to do that, I need some kind of `if-else` statement so that I can specify which collection I want to look at.

A pseudo-code of what my aggregation pipeline should do:

```sh
Group all documents by Category
if reference_field is "Not Deleted"
then $lookup on Collection mentioned in Category
else $lookup on the deleted_reference_field Collection (Project in this case)
```

**Current aggregation code:**
My current pipeline not at all efficient. I am going though *N* documents, everytime I have a different category and different value of `deleted_reference_field`. It looks like this:

```
db.events.aggregate([
    {
    "$facet": {
        "comments": [
            {"$match": {"category": "Comment"}},
            {"$match": {"deleted_reference_field": "Not Deleted"}},
            {
                "$lookup": {
                    "from": "comment",
                    "localField": "reference_field",
                    "foreignField": "_id",
                    "as": "Comments",
                }
            },
            {"$unwind": "$Comments"},
            {"$match": {"Comments.project_id": bson.ObjectId(project_id)}},
        ],
        "deleted_comments": [
            {"$match": {"category": "Comment"}},
            {"$match": {"deleted_reference_field": "Project"}},
            {"$match": {"reference_field": bson.ObjectId(project_id)}},
        ]}
    }

])
```

As you can see, there are 2 "buckets", one for **comments** and one for **deleted_comemnts**. Therefore, everytime I am creating a bucket, I am going through ALL the documents to filter out the documents that have Category as "Comment" and `deleted_reference_field` as either "Not Deleted" or "Project". There are about 7-8 categories (I have shown only Comment), for which I have followed the same process, hence proving to be very inefficient.

Hence, I want to reduce this massive complexity by grouping all the documents based on **Category** and further group them based on the value in the `deleted_reference_field`.

In short:

> How do I build an aggregation pipeline that can perform conditional lookups due to documents being fetched from different collections entirely.